# cordova splashscreen plugin ios universal anyany your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 when submitting to the app store

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, splash-screen

I use **cordova-plugin-splashscreen** with only one entry in my config.xml as follow:

```
<platform name="ios">
<splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
</platform>
```

When I run this app on iOS as debug or an archived .ipa file, my splash screen shows up fine on every device. When I submit this app on the App Store, I get this error :

> Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and app
>   updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must
>   include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under
>   UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}.
>   Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your
>   bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your
>   launch images.

I thought the universal file could be used for every device without worrying about resolutions and what not.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?